# How to have syntax highlighting in wordpress.com blogs?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Is there a way I could install some plugin or have syntax highlighting for my wordpress.com blog or do I need to install WP on my own server to be able to install a plugin to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress.com uses [Alex Gorbatchev’s SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter) so all you need to do is use the right shortcode ex:

```
[code language="css"]
#button {
font-weight: bold;
border: 2px solid #fff;
}
[/code]
```

which gives you something like this:

[image]

it has more features and you can see a list of supported languages at http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

Comment: Simple `code` instead of `sourcecode` works fine.

Comment: Is it possible to import highlight.js into wordpress.com - free plan?
I have imported my blogger posts into WP, but my syntaxhighlighter is gone, of course...

Comment: Does it work for Preview? or I need to publish to see the highlight.

Answer (score -2):

There is a plugin call "SyntaxHighlighter" really nice and easy. I am using on my blog. here is the link http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: Please read the question carefully - the question is about WordPress.com but not about a site on the person's own server (upon which plugins can be installed freely)